# Confusion with jQuery mouseout event

Tags: jquery, mouse, mouseout

My HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">cx</div>
</div>
```

When I use jQuery

```
$('#parent').mouseout(function(){
    //something here
});
```

I wonder why when my mouse enter the child `div` the function fires. I'm still inside parent `div`.
I want that `mouseout` function to fire only when I leave the parent `div` not when I'm on any child `div`.

http://jsbin.com/esiju/ << example

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350639/how-to-disable-mouseout-events-triggered-by-child-elements

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is what the `mouseleave` event is for.

```
$('#parent').mouseleave(function(){
//something here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Answer (score 1):

`.mouseleave` works perfectly here:

```
$("#parent").mouseleave(function(){
    //Enter stuff that should happen when mouse leaves 
    //the boundaries of the parent element
    // NOT including the children
});
```

`.mouseout` fires on mousing over child elements!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bit of difference between the mouseout and mouseover events.  jimyi has the correct solution for your problem, I just wanted to include some additional links for completeness.

- [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html)
- [Quick example of mouseout and mouseleave](http://kajaxnet.blogspot.com/2008/07/jquery-mouseleave-vs-mouseout.html)
- [What looks like a much more in depth look at the difference between mouseout and mouseleave](http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/15/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-for-firefox-and-other-non-ie-browsers/)