# JavaScript mouseover/mouseout issue with child element

Tags: javascript, parent-child, mouseover, mouseout

I have this little problem and I am requesting for your help.
I have a **div** element, inside which I have an **img** element, like this

```
<div id="parent" onmouseover="MyFuncHover()" onmouseout="MyFuncOut()">
    <img id="child" src="button.png" style="visibility: hidden" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFuncHover() {
        // Here I have some code that makes the "child" visible
    }

    function MyFuncOut() {
        // Here I have some code that makes the "child" invisible again
    }
</script>
```

As you, see, the image is a child of the **div**. I want that only when I leave the **div**, the child to disappear. Yet, it looks like when I move the mouse over the image, the *MyFuncOut()* function is called (because, I suppose, I leave the div by hovering the image). I don't want that to happen. I want the *MyFuncOut()* function to be called only when I leave the **div** area.

I didn't know that when you move your mouse over a child control, it's parent calls the mouseout event (even if I am over the child, I am still over the parent, too). I am trapped into this and I need a little of your good advice. Thanks!

**CHANGES**

O.K. Event bubbling will not send the "mouseout" event to the parent when I "mouseout" the child. It also won't send the "mouseover" event to the parent when I "mouseover" the child. That's not what I need. I need the "mouseout" event of the parent to not be sent when I "mouseover" the child. Get it? Event bubbling is useful when I don't want, for example, a click event on the child to be propagated to the parent, but this is not my case. What is weird is that I have other elements inside the same parent that don't fire the "mouseout" event of the parent when I "mouseover" them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events available in jquery, here is the below code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#parent").mouseenter(function () {
            $("#child").show();
        });
        $("#parent").mouseleave(function () {
            $("#child").hide();
        });
    });
```

above is to attach an event,

```
<div id="parent">
    <img id="child" src="button.png" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

Comment: I wanna do it with JavaScript only, thanks anyway, could be a last solution.

Comment: @ali mouseleave is actually a plain javascript event, so you can ignore the jQuery part and just use it directly.  the only difference between it and mouseleave is it doesn't bubble, so the child mouseleave won't cause the parent to get the same event.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the solution below, which it's pure javascript and I used with success.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

function mouseTracking(e) {
    mouse.x = e.clientX || e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY || e.pageY;
    var containerRectangle = container.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (mouse.x > containerRectangle.left && mouse.x < containerRectangle.right &&
            mouse.y > containerRectangle.top && mouse.y < containerRectangle.bottom) {
        // Mouse is inside container.
    } else {
        // Mouse is outside container.
    }
}
document.onmousemove = function () {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            mouseTracking(e);
        }, false);
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
        // For IE8 and earlier versions.
        mouseTracking(window.event);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank...I think it's very good solution because it can be used with addEventListener for dynamic binding event for elements

Answer (score 4):

Just add an if statement to your MyFuncOut function which checks the target is not the image

```
if (event.target !== imageNode) {
     imageNode.style.display = 'none'
}
```

Comment: here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/HvMjN/4/ using the method I was talking about above. It turns out the more modern event mouseout and mouseenter have the behaviour you originally expected so you can use your code just change the event types http://jsfiddle.net/HvMjN/6/

Comment: Thanks man, the only problem is that it doesn't work on IE6 (Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'). Yet, I think that can be solved by directly parent.onmouseover

Comment: just search cross browser event binding. ie6 uses attatchEvent

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with this too and couldn't get it to work. This is what I did instead. It's much easier and isn't JavaScript so it's faster and can't be turned off.

```
div.container {
    opacity:0.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity="00");
}

div.container:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity="100");
}
```

You can even add the CSS3 transition for opacity to give it a smoother feel to it.

Comment: Or simply just give it visibility:hidden on the normal and visibility:visible on the hover.

Comment: This filter:alpha(opacity="100"); is for IE the other is for every other browser.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set css of the child element pointer-event:none;
See example:

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#child {
  width: 200px;
  pointer-events: none; # this does the trick
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" onmouseover="MyFuncHover()" onmouseout="MyFuncOut()">
    <img id="child" src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?w=640&ssl=1" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFuncHover() {
      console.log("mouse over")
    }

    function MyFuncOut() {
      console.log("mouse out")
    }
</script>
```

Comment: if i have child as link it will disable link(