# Simple fadeIn fadeOut on hover div

Tags: jquery, parent, fadein, fadeout

I'm new to jQuery and am really struggling with this one. I've read some past posts and tried to figure it out myself but still stuck.

Basically I would like a fadeIn effect on a child when entering a parent div and a fadeOut effect on the child when leaving the parent. At the moment, it fade's in fine, but when I enter the child div that suddenly fades out.

See my fiddle for more info.

Any info sent on is much appreciated.

Comment: where is your fiddle? :)

Comment: Better yet, post your code here (in addition to providing a fiddle link).

Comment: Sorry thought I added :  http://jsfiddle.net/headex/XD5MV/

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent onmouseout when hovering child element of the parent absolute div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697758/prevent-onmouseout-when-hovering-child-element-of-the-parent-absolute-div)

Comment: No that is something different entirely. But thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below code in script tag.

```
$(function() {
    $('#ms8container').hover(function() {
        $('#videoButtonContainer').fadeIn('slow');
      },
      function(){
        $('#videoButtonContainer').fadeOut('slow');
      }
   );
});
```