# onMouseOut effect fired when mouse cursor goes to child div.... I dont want to do that

Tags: onmouseout

Here is  my code --

```
<li>
<a  id="LoginTxt2" onmouseover="MouseOver(this);" onmouseout="MouseOut(this);" href="#">
<div style="background-color:#CCC;">OLD Text</div>
</a>
</li>
```

JS--

```
MouseOver = function(obj){
    var id = obj.id;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='<div style="background-color:#DDD;">NEW Text</div>';

 }
MouseOut  = function(obj){
    var id = obj.id;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="<div style="background-color:#CCC;">OLD Text</div>";

 }
```

when my mouse goes to child div, MouseOut  fierd i dont want to do that... plz help

Answer (score 0):

This is the way the event works and there's no way of avoiding the `MouseOut()` function to be called. What you can do is check, inside the `MouseOut()` function, if the element you're now hovering is a child element of the outer element:

```
MouseOut = function(obj, event) {
    // this is the original element the event handler was assigned to
    var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;

    // check for all children levels (checking from bottom up)
    while (e && e.parentNode && e.parentNode != window) {
        if (e.parentNode == this||  e == this) {
            if(e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            return false;
        }
        e = e.parentNode;
    }
    var id = obj.id;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="<div style="background-color:#CCC;">OLD Text</div>";
}
```

Note that you need to change the `onmouseout` declaration to `onmouseout="MouseOut(this,event);"`.

NOTE: solution derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13141057/1417546