# how can I check when the mouse is out of any of the children elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a very novice question (I am mad I couldnt solve it). I have a problem due I an triggering an action everytime the mouse leaves a container, the problem now its I have children elements, and for some reason, when I move over a children element my action gets triggered.

I basically have something like this

```
<li>
<image>
<div>content</div>
</li>
```

I want when I enter to my li, its active and when i go out from it gets unactive, but i can enter and hover and all over my content, any idea how to do this?

I checked this but no results
[Prevent onmouseout when hovering child element of the parent absolute div WITHOUT jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697758/prevent-onmouseout-when-hovering-child-element-of-the-parent-absolute-div)

Thanks

Comment: you do not want any action on the children elements right? you want it to hover only on the parent?

Comment: The mouseleave event is not triggered on nested children -> http://jsfiddle.net/WNgAb/

Comment: hi, when i hover on the parent, i want to show the children, just making a .show over some divs of the content, nothing else, but i can make them with css adding a class at the parent if is not possible later with the javascript

Comment: heres a jsfiddle updated on adeneo's answer
http://jsfiddle.net/dxeEV/

Answer (score 2):

I personally take the lazy way out and use jQuery's [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method to set them both at once rather than use mousein and mouseout separately.
This lets jQuery deal with children in and out, something like:

```
jQuery("li").hover(function() {
  //mousein actions
 },
 function() {
  //mouseout actions
 }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent stuff from happening when hovering the children, just check that the target is in fact the bound element :

```
$('li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if ( e.target === this ) {
        // do stuff here
    }
});
```