# How to make onMouseLeave in React include the child context?

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent

I am currently building a dropdown button to learn React. I have made two onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events in the parent div to make it visible when hovering it disappear when not. The problem is that those events only stick to parent.

How to make onMouseLeave in React include the child context?
Or, how can I keep the state expand be true when hovering on children?

```
class DropDownButton extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleHoverOn = this.handleHoverOn.bind(this);
    this.handleHoverOff = this.handleHoverOff.bind(this);
    this.state = {expand: false};
}

handleHoverOn(){
    if(this.props.hover){
        this.setState({expand: true});
    }
}

handleHoverOff(){
    if(this.props.hover){
        this.setState({expand: false});
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={styles.listTitle}
            onMouseEnter={this.handleHoverOn}
            onMouseLeave={this.handleHoverOff}>
            {this.props.name}
            </div>
            <div>
            {React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child){
            return React.cloneElement(child, {className: 'child'});
            })}
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two different `div`s in your DOM that don't overlap; I'll split up `render` so it's more obvious:

```javascript
render() {
    return (
        <div>

            <div className={styles.listTitle}
              onMouseEnter={this.handleHoverOn}
              onMouseLeave={this.handleHoverOff}>
                {this.props.name}
            </div>

            <div>
                {React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child){
                    return React.cloneElement(child, {className: 'child'});
                })}
            </div>

        </div>
     );
}
```

The `div` that has the `onMouseLeave` attached to it does not contain the children; so, when the mouse moves to hover on a child, it leaves the `div` and `this.handleHoverOff` is called.

You might consider using CSS to hide the children if they shouldn't be displayed, or conditionally rendering them:

```javascript
render() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.listTitle}
          onMouseEnter={this.handleHoverOn}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleHoverOff}>
            {this.props.name}
            {this.state.expanded && this.renderChildren()}
        </div>
     );
},

renderChildren() {
    return (
        <div>
            {React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child){
                return React.cloneElement(child, {className: 'child'});
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It works. I did a stupid mistake, and the conditional rendering is useful for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

By using the on mouse leave instead of mouse out and blocking the event on the children I got it reliably working no matter how fast I move through my list items.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837002/3302764