# Prevent user from leaving view if there are unsaved changes without using routes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a panel that opens like a modal from right to left.
Inside the panel I have a left navigation with different options that when clicking render different components.

These components are forms and I wanna prompt the user if he navigates away from a component while having unsaved changes.

I cannot use react routes since I have no routes for these, theyre just components.

Is there a way so that I cant prevent the user from navigating away or from unmounting the component and display that popup?

Answer (score -2):

If it is an input you can use [onBlur](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#onblur)

or [onMouseLeave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036028/how-to-make-onmouseleave-in-react-include-the-child-context) if the mouse leave the component

Comment: I dont understand what ur saying,  onblur or onmousleave serve no purpose here. Read the question once more

Comment: @MuhamedKrasniqi what i am implying is that you can use both event handlers above to fire and function and just say use an alert() to display the massage you want to