# Value of 'this' inside a mouse event handler

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I was struggling a bit to handle the `mouseout` event on a div with a bunch of nested elements. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13141057), which helped me, but leaves me with a further question.

The proposed answser uses `this` in the event handler and as far as I could test it effectively points to the element to which the handler was originally attached, and not its descendants.

My question is : is that documented somewhere ? I can't seem to find it on MDN.

Comment: post the code please

Comment: [What about here?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler)

Comment: @MikeC : right on, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) document?

About the handle function :

> As a DOM event handler
>   When a function is used as an event handler, its this is set to the element the event fired from (some browsers do not follow this convention for listeners added dynamically with methods other than addEventListener).