# calling javascript event only once for parent div element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call **onmouseout** event on parent div.

Although function **outofdiv** is called once cursor goes out of parent div.

But **function is again called** when cursor travel between different child div which I don't want to happen

please suggest any method using **javascript** only

```
 <div id="maze"  onmouseout="outofdiv();">

            <div id="start" onClick="start();">S</div>
            <div class="boundary"></div>
            <div class="boundary"></div>
            <div class="boundary"></div>
            <div class="boundary"></div>
            <div class="boundary"></div>
            <div id="end" onClick="end();">E</div>
</div>


function outofdiv(){
alert("something")
```

Comment: What does `outofdiv()` does? Can you please elaborate more on the problem

Comment: @GowthamShiva It's not about the function; the OP has just misunderstood the usage of `onmouseout`. According to W3Schools: _"The onmouseout event occurs when the mouse pointer is moved out of an element, or out of one of its children."_

Comment: please suggest any way to alert something when mouse pointer moves out of parent div not when traverses between child element

Comment: Thank you @JamesDouglas I got answer form this question I should use onmouseleave simply

Answer (score 1):

This is called event bubbling. The `onmouseout` event is triggered by a child `div` element, and is bubbled up through its DOM hierarchy, in this case to the parent `div`'s `onmouseout` event handler.

You can use [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to determine if an event has been bubbled or not.

Put

```
if (event.target!=event.currentTarget) return;
```

as the first line of your `outofdiv` function. This prevents the function from continuing if the parent `div` is not the originator of the `onmouseout` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer here: [Prevent onmouseout when hovering child element of the parent absolute div WITHOUT jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697758/prevent-onmouseout-when-hovering-child-element-of-the-parent-absolute-div-withou)

but to sum it up, you have to use another function:

```
function onMouseOut(event) {
  //this is the original element the event handler was assigned to
  var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
  if (e.parentNode == this || e == this) {
    return;
  }
  alert('MouseOut');
  // handle mouse event here!
}

document.getElementById('maze').addEventListener('mouseout',onMouseOut,true);
```

Code taken and modified from the first answer in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it might be helpful to you

```js
var i = 0;
$( "div.overout" )
  .mouseover(function() {
    i += 1;
    $( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse over x " + i );
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse out " );
  });
 
var n = 0;
$( "div.enterleave" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
    n += 1;
    $( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse enter x " + n );
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $( this ).find( "span" ).text( "mouse leave" );
  });
```

```css
  div.out {
    width: 40%;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    background-color: #d6edfc;
    float: left;
  }
  div.in {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: #fc0;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  p {
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


 
<div class="out overout">
  <span>move your mouse</span>
  <div class="in">
  </div>
</div>
 
<div class="out enterleave">
  <span>move your mouse</span>
  <div class="in">
  </div>
</div>
```

you can also refer this link https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: 1) You haven't included jQuery in your example so it does nothing; 2) The OP clearly stated: _"please suggest any method using **javascript** only"_

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following JavaScript:

```
var i = 0;
function outofdiv() {
  if (!i++) {
    alert("something");
  }
}
```

This will call only once for single page load.