# Prevent triggering onMouseOut event when hover over children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I have a `div` element and two children inside it. I want to show `.portfolio-overlay` when user hover over `.portfolio-item` and hide it when they leave that element.

```
const handleHover = () => {
        gsap.fromTo(overlay.current, {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1, duration: .5});
    };

const handleLeave = () => {
     gsap.fromTo(overlay.current, {opacity: 1}, {opacity: 0, duration: .5});
};

<div className="portfolio-item" onMouseOver={handleHover} onMouseOut={handleLeave}>
     <div ref={overlay} className="portfolio-overlay">
           <h3>My header1</h3>
           <h4>My header2</h4>
     </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I did that with `gsap`. But the problem is when I hover over `h3` or `h4`, `handleLeave()` and `handleHover()` functions are triggered and I see both animations again. How could I prevent that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent onmouseout when hovering child element of the parent absolute div WITHOUT jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697758/prevent-onmouseout-when-hovering-child-element-of-the-parent-absolute-div-withou)

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: It does. Your question is an exact duplicate. Try the answers out.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the attribute "tabindex='-1'".

```
const handleHover = () => {
    gsap.fromTo(overlay.current, {opacity: 0}, {opacity: 1, duration: .5});
};

const handleLeave = () => {
     gsap.fromTo(overlay.current, {opacity: 1}, {opacity: 0, duration: .5});
};

<div tabindex="-1" className="portfolio-item" onMouseOver={handleHover} onMouseOut={handleLeave}>
     <div ref={overlay} className="portfolio-overlay">
           <h3>My header1</h3>
           <h4>My header2</h4>
     </div>
</div>
```