# Prevent onmouseout from firing in Blazor when moving over a child element

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697758/prevent-onmouseout-when-hovering-child-element-of-the-parent-absolute-div-withou) but involving Blazor.  I have a div that works like a popup menu which which contains child elements that the user can click on to do something.  I would like the popup div to disappear when the user moves the mouse off of it.  I can use the onmouseout event, but the problem is that moving the mouse over the child elements within the popup div triggers that event. I want onmouseout to fire only when the mouse moves out of the parent div.  The only solution I found so far that kind of works is to use CSS to set "pointer-events: none;" on the child elements.  But that also disables the click event on them, which I want to maintain.  Blazor does not support onmouseleave which is recommended elsewhere.

So how can I use the onmouseout event in Blazor on a div which is not triggered by its child elements?

**UPDATE:**

Cory's answer to use @onmouseout:preventDefault on the child elements did work.  But the mouseout event did not fire reliably.  I successfully found a work around by setting classes on the div container when showing the popup and used CSS onhover to hide and show it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210033/using-only-css-show-div-on-hover-over-a)

Comment: You can add JavaScript to a blazor component.

Comment: The popup div is opened by setting a bool value to true in the Razor page.  Using JavaScript to hide it seems quite ooky.

Comment: @Rono Glad you got it working!

Comment: Hey @Rono if you can add some code on how you actually did it, that would be great. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be right but couldn't you use `@onmouseout:preventDefault` or `@onmouseout:stopPropagation` on the child HTML elements?

I haven't tested of course, but these exist for all Blazor events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#prevent-default-actions

Answer (score 0):

Slight deviation but this solved the issue for me:

Instead of:

```
onmouseover
onmouseout
```

I used:

```
onmouseenter
onmouseleave
```

In my case this applied to the use case where I wanted to show / hide an overlay for a card.

```
<div class="template" onmouseenter="@this.MouseOver" onmouseleave="@this.MouseOut">
```