# Show and Hide a Div on mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, css

I want to open a div containing few links in it on mouseover of an image and to hide that div on mouse out. but the problem i am facing is that the div also hides when i try to go on any link of that div coz the mouseout event of image fires which hide the div.

Comment: may this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350639/how-to-disable-mouseout-events-triggered-by-child-elements

Answer (score 1):

use

```
transition-delay:some value in sec;
```

and on

```
div:hover {
display:block; 
}
```

and for full help show us the code

Answer (score 0):

check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/TEyHC/11/) this is big help for me in my previous work maybe can help you also...

Jquery

```
$(function() {

                $('#selectBox').click(function() {
            $('.selectBoxContent').slideToggle('fast');
            return false;

        });
            });
```