# Hovering over absolute positioned element registers a mouseout

Tags: jquery, css

[See issue here](http://tj.localsportswire.org/index.cfm?member_id=5&action=media&content_action=photos)

When I hover over the image, it zooms, but when i hover over the caption, the zoom resets. Its like the absolute positioned element registers a mouseout.

```
.tint {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    background-color:#111;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  }


figure {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    width:75%;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
    font-family:Cachet;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1000;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
}

figcaption:hover
{

}

figure:before {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 800;
    background: black;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
    color: black;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius:    12px;
    border-radius:         12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

figure:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
}

.cap-bot:before { bottom: 0%; left: 0%; }
.cap-bot figcaption { left: 15%; bottom: 0%;}
.cap-bot:hover figcaption { bottom: 30%;left:15%;}

.zoom
{
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: transform 1s;
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: pointer;    
]


.gallery_grid_image {
    display: block;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    transition: opacity .3s linear;
}
```

Any ideas? I am using Jquery to add the zoom class.

```
            $(".comment_preview").on({
                "mouseover" : function() {
                    $(this).find('.gallery_grid_image').addClass('zoom');
                },
                "mouseout" : function() {
                    $(this).find('.gallery_grid_image').removeClass('zoom');
                }
            });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350639/how-to-disable-mouseout-events-triggered-by-child-elements

Answer (score 0):

Use `pointer-event: none;` to tell everything to ignore that element.

[MDN: pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events?v=example)